# mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE member_db SET 'Fine_Amt'=('Fine_Amt' +' $fine') WHERE 'Member_id' = '$mem_id'"); not getting executed

Tags: php, mysql

I've trying to run the following query but getting the desired result:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE 'member_db' SET 'Fine_Amt'=('Fine_Amt' +'$fine') WHERE 'Member_id' = '$mem_id'");
```

where, $fine is being forwarded in the URL from another page and $mem_id is the Primary key of member_db.

For the above query, the value getting stored in the 'Fine_Amt' field is 0

However, if I remove '$fine' with a constant value (say 100)

```
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE member_db SET 'Fine_Amt'=('Fine_Amt' + 100) WHERE 'Member_id' = '$mem_id'");
```

The query works fine.

Comment: You probably have a SQL injection vulnerability in this code.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: You need to use a technique called _parameter binding_. Search for it, or there is an [example in the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). At present if you take values from `$_GET` or `$_POST` without cleaning them, you may allow an attacker to run their own SQL statements on your database, which will compromise your security or your users' privacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the unnecessary quotes

```
mysqli_query(
    $conn,
    "UPDATE member_db SET Fine_Amt=(Fine_Amt + " . $fine . ") WHERE Member_id = " . $mem_id
);
```

Comment: btw, I've also corrected the $fine value which I was getting in the url, which was not proper

Comment: I would generally expect any answers to this sort of question to make an explicit note about the security risks in not using parameter binding. This should be the first observation, really, otherwise the OP will continue to write and publish unsafe code.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the variables like this:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE 'member_db' SET 'Fine_Amt'=('Fine_Amt' +'" . $fine . "') WHERE 'Member_id' = '" . $mem_id . "'");
```

Comment: I would generally expect any answers to this sort of question to make an explicit note about the security risks in not using parameter binding. This should be the first observation, really, otherwise the OP will continue to write and publish unsafe code.